# NEED HELP to send an string to another viewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

My NSString dynamically generated in a tableview who should be send to another viewcontroller: (message)

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

LoanModel* loan = _feed.users[indexPath.row];

NSString* message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ from",
                     loan.name
                     ];
     }
```

The DetailViewController who should be get the message

```
  //  DetailViewController.h

  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

  @interface DetailViewController : UIViewController

  @property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;

  @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *message;

  @end
```

What is the procedure to connect the message to my label named name ? (with assistant editor)
Thanks

Comment: why send string to another view controller if that view controller is not seen yet? i'm asking in order to understand what exactly you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

you can either create a delegate protocol and call some method in detail page to set the message or instantiate the detail view by passing the message.